# Getting form data in nodeJS with Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to make my first website in NodeJS with Jade and Express. Now I want to make a form on a page called Lipinsky but I can't figure out how I can store the input into a variable.
I tried console.logging res and req and they're big objects without any body, so req.body is undefined. 
My app.js for rendering and getting the form looks like this:

```
app.get('/lipinsky', function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    let html = lipinsky({ title: 'Lipinsky RO5' })
    res.send(html)
  } catch (e) {
    next(e)
  }
})

app.post('/lipinsky', function (req, res) {
    let html = lipinsky({ title: 'Lipinsky RO5' })
    res.send(html);
});
```

And my lipinsky.jade is:

```
extend default

block content
  h3.
    Lipinsky rule of five calculator

  p.
    Calculate Lipinsky RO5 for molecules with a known CAS registry number.
  div
  form(action='/lipinsky',method='post')
    div(data-role='fieldcontain')
      fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
        label(for='name') Molecule name 
           input(id='name',type='text',value='',name='name')
```

So I don't know if I'm doing it right and how to get the entered form data into a variable in app.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the hell is `lipinsky()`?
1. Anyway, you can use `res.render( { title: "foo" } )` to render the template and return it.
2. And you haven't used `title` in you jade.

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    body
        h3= title
```

3. I guess you haven't added any middleware. So, you should not call `next(e)`.

```
app.get('/lipinsky', function (req, res) {
    res.render("./views/lipinsky", {title: "foo"});
})
```

Comment: ROFL that lipinsky()

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, I see now how clueless I was. I should have a good look at the tutorials again haha.
However, when I try to log ```req.body```, it still returns undefined.
The calling lipinsky as if it is a function comes from http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/a-simple-website-in-node-js-2016-edition and I have no idea why they would do that.

Comment: Make sure you have really posted anything. I use postman, a chrome extension to test the server. BTW, I cannot find `lipinsky` on the page.@bdbdbd